# testing 2-player socket.io game. updating a label is affecting both pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I don't understand why updating a label on one page is affecting the label on another page. I did not think the DOM was shared like that. Opening one tab or page successfully updates the label to 'player1', but when I open another tab/pg, it updates both labels to 'player2'.

```
<script>
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('connect', function() {
socket.emit('join');
socket.on('joinSuccess', function (playerSlot) {
  if (playerSlot === 'player1') {
   $("#playerID").text("you are player1");
} else if (playerSlot === 'player2') {
   $("#playerID").text("you are player2");
  }
}); //end joinSuccess
}); //end connect
```

I am merely trying to notify the user which player they are.

---

solution:

```
 else if (playerSlot === 'player2') {
    var elm = $("#playerID");
    var empty = !elm.text().trim();
    if (empty) {
      elm.text("you are " + playerSlot);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Are you pushing the 'joinSuccess' message when new user joins? In such case this message will be passed to both the pages with same playerSlot value. So, all pages will be updated last joined player name.

Comment: I'm not an expert on socket.io, but it seems likely that `joinSuccess` gets triggered on all existing tabs when a new tab opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you pushing the 'joinSuccess' message when new user joins? In such case this message will be passed to both the pages with same playerSlot value. So, all pages will be updated last joined player name.

In such case you can handle this with simple condition,

```
socket.on('joinSuccess', function (playerSlot) {
  var elm = $("#playerID"); 
  if (!elm.text().trim()) {
    elm.text("you are " + playerSlot);
  }
});
```

Comment: $("#playerID").text()  is empty initially or it has some default value?

Comment: Sorry I still had my old statement outside the if. Once I removed that, it worked.

Comment: is that condition checking if the text is empty? So for the player1 page, you leave it alone?

Comment: Yes. It checks whether the label is empty. if it is already updated - it wont come inside the condition for further updates